# How can I parse this json with Python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, jsonparser

I have a json file and I need to parse it to the jsons seperatly. Here is the json:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
 {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "@id": "relation/280991",
    "admin_level": 6,
    "boundary": "administrative",
    "name": "Çumra",
    "network": "TR42-districts",
    "type": "boundary"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          32.8265346,
          37.328043
        ],
        ...
        [
          32.9993334,
          37.4505836
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "id": "relation/280991"
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "@id": "relation/281080",
    "admin_level": 6,
    "alt_name": "Kozakli",
    "boundary": "administrative",
    "name": "Kozaklı",
    "name:ru": "Козаклы",
    "network": "TR50-districts",
    "postal_code": 50600,
    "type": "boundary"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          34.5845556,
          39.3227159
        ],
        ...
        [
          34.5845556,
          39.3227159
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "id": "relation/281080"
  }
 ]
}
```

So, in this JSON, I want to take only including "network" : "TR35-districts" ones with coordinates etc. Can you guys help me to do that?

Format should be like: type, properties, geometry but only if its TR35-districts.

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: You'll find this useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html